# How is a range variable selected when using a database

Tags: asp.net, database, variables, model-view-controller

I am trying to add an actionresult that displays data from a table, but I am new to MVC and ASP.NET in general.  I want to add some references to a table but one thing I'm unsure on is how the Range Variables work.  In the following example, which I feel is similar to what I'd end up writing, how does the programmer know to use "u" or "reff?"  I cannot find an area in the app that indicates those variables as a direct link to information in the db.  I hope this makes sense, I've asked some "bad" questions lately but really depend on this site, so if it doesn't make sense it's just because I'm still learning how to even talk about MVC, it's very new to me.

```
var rUsers = from u in db.Users
                        from reff in db.Referrals
                        where u.Email == reff.ReferralEmail
                        select reff;
```

Comment: `... know to use "u" or "reff?"` => I am not sure what you are asking here. Define `use`

Comment: In this code, the variable "u" and the term/variable "reff," I am wondering what those signify.  I understand they are referring to a portion of the db but I don't understand why "u" is used, does 'U" link to a portion of the db directly, could any other variable be used, how does one know to use "u" instead of "x, y, b, n, etc?"

Comment: ok, i understand your question. This is basic linq syntax, I recommend searching and following a linq tutorial (plenty of them out there). Search term would be [c# linq tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+linq+tutorial).